# How to get first class name dynamically added using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have multiple div element's which is generated dynamically. I want to access the first class name using javascript. So far i did this:

```
function changeFilter(cat) {
   console.log(cat);
   var x = {};
   x = document.getElementsByClassName("itemProductList");
   console.log(x);
   if (cat == x) {
     console.log("yes");
   } else {
     console.log("nope");
   }
}
```

In console I get this:

```
div.Desserts.itemProductList.item-list.col-md-3.col-lg-3.col-xs-12.col-sm-4,
```

My div elements that are generated dynamically looks something like this:

```
<div class="{{product.category}} itemProductList item-list col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-4" style="float:left; min-height:370px; margin-bottom:20px;" ng-repeat="product in store.products | filter:search | filter:category">
```

How can I get `Deserts` from above?

Can someone help me out?

Comment: It's not a good idea to expect that class names will be in any particular order. You'd have much more stable code if you'd use an identifiable class name, like `category--Desserts`. That way you can look through the list of class names looking for that pattern, and your code will still work no matter how the set of classes is affected by other code.

Comment: Why you require to retrieve the class name? If you require that data to be present for your html to be accessed in javascript. You can create your own custom attribute and use it to get data.

Comment: You already have that value inside `product.category`. Why do need DOM API to fetch it?

Comment: @adiga, i need to hide rest of the elements that do not match. if i get `desserts` in both `cat` and `x`, then the rest of the items should not be visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the element's classname on a space and get the first part of that array.

[`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a HTMLCollection which you can iterate over with a `for` loop.

```
for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
    console.log(x[i].className.split(" ")[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `classList` property and take the first element.

The function `document.getElementsByClassName()` will return an iterable with possibly many items, so you can use `Array.forEach()` to iterate over them, but you have to convert the result to an array first:

```js
const divs = document.getElementsByClassName("itemProductList");
[...divs].forEach(div => console.log(div.classList[0]));
```

```html
<div class="Desert itemProductList item-list col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
<div class="Desert itemProductList item-list col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
<div class="Desert itemProductList item-list col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
```